# Is this lower bound on the singular values of the sum of two matrices correct?

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, lower-bounds, singular-values

Equation 7 of [this paper (Ramazan Türkmen, Zübeyde Ulukök, *Inequalities for Singular Values of Positive Semidefinite Block Matrices*, International Mathematical Forum, Vol. 6, 2011, no. 31, 1535 - 1545)](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-2011/29-32-2011/ulukokIMF29-32-2011.pdf) says that it is well known that, given two complex-valued matrices $A$ and $B$, it holds

$$\sigma_j(A+B) \geq \sigma_j(A)+\lambda_n(B)$$

where $\sigma_j$ is the $j$-th singular value and $\lambda_n$ is the $n$-th eigenvalue

1. Is this correct? Do we need some hypotheses on $A$, $B$?
2. Can somebody point me to a reference?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems a little tough if $B=-A$.

Comment: I see. But in this case $\sigma_j(0)=0\geq \sigma_j(A)-\lambda_1(A)$. I think this is possible.

Comment: No. Take $B$ the identity and $A=-B$. Your inequality reads $0 \geq 2$.

Comment: I think the title of paper gives a hint that the matrices are expected to be positive semi definite.

Comment: That's Weyl inequality when $A$ and $B$ are hermitian.

Comment: The answer box is a little lower. Show that you are not afraid of downvotes and post your answers as answers. :)

Comment: I think I found the resolution to the above concerns (see my answer below). There's no expectation of the matrices being psd (though the inequality as stated is incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

Jumping in many years later, but I believe there's a typo in the paper which originates from Zhang's 1999 matrix theory book.

The first clue that something is wrong is that $\lambda_n(B)$ for an arbitrary complex matrix $B$ may not be a real number, and so the inequality as a whole doesn't make any sense.

After going through the proof of Theorem 7.11 in Zhang's book (which is referenced in the paper you linked for this inequality), I believe that $\lambda_n(B)$ actually means $\lambda_n(\mathcal{H}(B))$, where
$$\begin{align} \mathcal{H}(B) &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B\\
B^* & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
whence $\lambda_n(\mathcal{H}(B)) = -\sigma_1(B)$, and so the desired inequality actually reads
$$ \sigma_j(A + B) \ge \sigma_j(A) - \sigma_1(B) $$